# Can I render Swagger docs directly by following the YAML file link in GitHub repo?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is there a way to eliminate the copy & paste step in order to render Swagger API documentation defined in YAML file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for the swagger UI, you can pass a URL directly to it, which will cause the UI to render the location that you specify:

http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/master/test/spec/v2/petstore.yaml

or with the swagger-editor, you can import directly from a url like such:

http://editor.swagger.io/#/?import=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/master/test/spec/v2/petstore.yaml#/

Comment: Is there any unique link to save and restore it (like jsffidle does)?